# Unable to receive USSD sessions while iPhone 5s screen is locked

Tags: ios, iphone

While my iPhone's screen is locked, I am not able to receive any USSD session on it. There is no notification of it as well. If I keep my screen on I receive it fine.

Is this a phone restriction or some network problem?

Answer (score 1):

USSD session messages no longer turn on the screen. This was intended to save battery.

I for once had a problem that the USSD message would arrive when the iPhone was in my pocket and the screen would be ON until I manually dismissed it, which would drain my battery.

Comment: Is there is an option available to enable it? To be more precise, I don't receive anything when my screen is locked. i.e not even a window of USSD when I turn it on.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I dont think there is an option to turn it on AFAIK